# in a react project (either normal project or micro frontend) to handle routing, what all webpack configurations are necessary?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, routes, configuration

This is theoretical question and what I expect is some  explanation, or any paperpublished or any link to the similar content.
All answers will  be appreciated.